# Best practices for handling paths in File Manager with MSM?

Tags: wygwam, file-manager, bestpractice

I have a secondary site in an MSM install (EE2.5.5).

In EE's File Manager, I have paths like this:

/assets/foldername
http://site2.com/assets/foldername

This works fine when using a *File* fieldtype, as I can change the domain name referenced above and file paths will all update. However, images inserted in a rich text field, i.e., WYGWAM, will be dumped in like this:

```
<img src="http://site2.com/assets/foldername/image.gif">
```

When I chance the domain name, I'll have broken links. However, if I try to refer to images with relative paths:

```
<img src="/assets/foldername/image.gif">
```

They don't show up in the EE control panel because it's running at site1.com/system

The only solution I've found to this is to store all the images at the primary domain and then reference them all with full paths starting with http://
Then I can fuss with the secondary domain and paths remain correct.

Answer (score 2):

WYGWAM inserts images with {filedirX} in place of the actual path to the image. So changing the domain name (or replacing site2.com/somefolder with /somefolder for folders within File Manager should work without a hitch. Thanks @kristengrote.